# Get Azure API Management SKU using REST API

Tags: rest, api, azure, azure-api-management, azure-cli

I'm trying to get api management sku condition using REST API but it doesn't work by occuring 401 Unauthorized error. However, I verified that the SAS is valid by trying to execute other API Management REST API.
I have no idea, please help me.

*API

```
URL=https://management.azure.com/subscriptions/mysubid/resourceGroups/myrg/providers/Microsoft.ApiManagement/service/myservice
API_VER=2017-03-01
SAS="**Generate by APIM Publisher portal**"

curl -i GET "$URL?api-version=$API_VER" -H "Authorization: $SAS"
```

*Error

```
HTTP/1.1 401 Unauthorized
Cache-Control: no-cache
Pragma: no-cache
Content-Type: application/json; charset=utf-8
Expires: -1
WWW-Authenticate: Bearer authorization_uri="https://login.windows.net/4cb021a3-bd70-42f3-91ef-******", error="invalid_token", error_description="The authentication scheme of SharedAccessSignature is not supported."
x-ms-failure-cause: gateway
x-ms-request-id: 2398890d-aeea-4580-******
x-ms-correlation-request-id: 2398890d-aeea-4580-b85b-******
x-ms-routing-request-id: JAPANWEST:20180129T071135Z:2398890d-aeea-4580-b85b-*******
Strict-Transport-Security: max-age=31536000; includeSubDomains
Date: Mon, 29 Jan 2018 07:11:35 GMT
Connection: close
Content-Length: 150

{"error":{"code":"AuthenticationFailedInvalidHeader","message":"Authentication failed. The 'Authorization' header is provided in an invalid format."}}
```

Comment: If you try `-H "Authorization: Bearer $SAS"`. does it work?

Comment: I also think you should get token using `curl -X "POST" "https://login.microsoftonline.com/$TENANTID/oauth2/token" \
-H "Cookie: flight-uxoptin=true; stsservicecookie=ests; x-ms-gateway-slice=productionb; stsservicecookie=ests" \
-H "Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded" \
--data-urlencode "client_id=$APPID" \
--data-urlencode "grant_type=client_credentials" \
--data-urlencode "client_secret=$PASSWORD" \
--data-urlencode "resource=https://management.azure.com/"`. Not token get on Portal.

Comment: Thanks for replying. Yes I tried it but it did not work. The error message changed to "The access token is invalid".

Comment: OK I will try it, too.

Comment: See my updated answer, I test in my lab, it works for me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You lose `Bearer` in your header token.

```
-H "Authorization: Bearer $SAS"
```

Also, the api you used is a [Azure Rest API](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/). The token is not your generate by APIM Publisher portal. You need create a [service principal](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-resource-manager/resource-group-create-service-principal-portal#create-an-azure-active-directory-application), then use it to get token. For example:

```
TENANTID=""
APPID=""
PASSWORD=""
curl -X "POST" "https://login.microsoftonline.com/$TENANTID/oauth2/token" \
-H "Cookie: flight-uxoptin=true; stsservicecookie=ests; x-ms-gateway-slice=productionb; stsservicecookie=ests" \
-H "Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded" \
--data-urlencode "client_id=$APPID" \
--data-urlencode "grant_type=client_credentials" \
--data-urlencode "client_secret=$PASSWORD" \
--data-urlencode "resource=https://management.azure.com/"
```

After you get token, you could use API to get the sku.

```
curl -X "GET" "https://management.azure.com/subscriptions/*********/resourceGroups/shuiapi/providers/Microsoft.ApiManagement/service/shuiapi?api-version=2017-03-01" \
    -H "Authorization: Bearer $token" \
    -H "Content-Type: application/json"
```

Comment: I appreciate for your helping promptly. I will accept your answer after verifying your solution but I have no authority about service principal setting so it will take some time .

Comment: OK, you need refer to this link https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-resource-manager/resource-group-create-service-principal-portal#create-an-azure-active-directory-application Create a sp firstly, then give it `Owner` role.

Comment: Hi, do you create service principal now? You also could do this with Azure Cli 2.0  https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cli/azure/create-an-azure-service-principal-azure-cli?toc=%2Fazure%2Fazure-resource-manager%2Ftoc.json&view=azure-cli-latest

Comment: Thank you for your updating. I created service principal, and I could get token successfully. However, it occurs an error below. "The client '2cf9f8a9-247b-4bae-bc98-****' with object id '2cf9f8a9-247b-4bae-*****' does not have authorization to perform action 'Microsoft.ApiManagement/service/read' over scope '/subscriptions/mysubid/resourceGroups/myrg/providers/Microsoft.ApiManagement/service/myservice". It seems that the url which is set at service difinition is wrong. What should I designate the url ?

Comment: Hi, you don't give your sp `Owner` role to your subscription.  https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-resource-manager/resource-group-create-service-principal-portal#assign-application-to-role

Comment: It works ! As you said, it wasn't assigned owner role. Thank you for your helping kindly :)

Comment: Another handy tool for getting a token to call ARM is this https://github.com/projectkudu/ARMClient

Comment: @DarrelMiller Thanks for your share.