# AuthenticationFailedInvalidHeader when using the Azure API Management REST API

Tags: rest, azure, authorization, azure-api-management, azure-cli

I'm willing to log stuff from my Azure Api Management into an eventhub using policies.

I'm following this documentation : https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/apimanagement/logger/createorupdate

Here is my HTTP Request (using Postman):

```
PUT /subscriptions/3f0a0802-0a42-4a73-82b2-094d41acd70a/resourceGroups/GRP-Poc-BilanHydrique/providers/Microsoft.ApiManagement/service/WaterBalance/loggers/end-user-logger?api-version=2017-03-01 HTTP/1.1
Host: management.azure.com
Authorization: {my token}
Content-Type: application/json
Cache-Control: no-cache
Postman-Token: 449f686d-3a86-b714-0b37-979567f6f921

{
  "properties": {
    "loggerType": "azureEventHub",
    "description": "adding a new logger",
    "credentials": {
      "name": "api-management-logs",
      "connectionString": "{my connection string}"
    }
  }
}
```

I generated my token from the Api Manager UI at this URL : /admin/tenant/access
I've checked the expiration.

It look like this :

```
SharedAccessSignature integration&{date}&{base64stuff}==
```

Here is a screenshot of where I created that token :
[screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kOog6.png)

And here you have the response :

```
{
"error": {
    "code": "AuthenticationFailedInvalidHeader",
    "message": "Échec de l'authentification. L'en-tête 'Authorization' est fourni dans un format incorrect."
}
```

I can't figure out what's going on. Any ideas ?
Is there a workaround ? Is there any way to create the api management logger through the azure portal ?

Thanks !

**UPDATE 01/30 :**

Thanks to your answers, I figured out it was not the right API. 
I've tried the API Management endpoint, and I get a 500 HTTP error :

Request :

```
PUT /loggers/end-user-logger?api-version=2018-01-01 HTTP/1.1
Host: waterbalance.management.azure-api.net
Authorization: SharedAccessSignature integration&201801301710&{secret}==
Content-Type: application/json
Cache-Control: no-cache
Postman-Token: 2618737b-af3e-c7d3-1d31-6b6f654100e9

{
  "properties": {
    "loggerType": "AzureEventHub",
    "description": "adding a new logger",
    "credentials": {
      "name": "end-user-logs",
      "connectionString": "Endpoint=sb://api-management-logs.servicebus.windows.net/;SharedAccessKeyName=Sending;SharedAccessKey={secret}"
    }
  }
}
```

Response:

```
     {
    "error": {
        "code": "InternalServerError",
        "message": "Request processing failed due to internal error.",
        "details": null
    }
```

It doesn't seem to be a token issue since i don't get a Unauthorized error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The API `PUT /subscriptions/3f0a0802-0a42-4a73-82b2-094d41acd70a/resourceGroups/GRP-Poc-BilanHydrique/providers/Microsoft.ApiManagement/service/WaterBalance/loggers/end-user-logger?api-version=2017-03-01 HTTP/1.1` you used is a Azure Rest APi, not API Management API.

For [Azure Rest API](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/#create-the-request), you need create a [service principal](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cli/azure/create-an-azure-service-principal-azure-cli?toc=%2Fazure%2Fazure-resource-manager%2Ftoc.json&view=azure-cli-latest) then use it to create a token.

[image]

When you call the API, the header is `Authorization: Bearer $token`

[image]

More information about this see this similar [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48496368/get-azure-api-management-sku-using-rest-api/48496419#48496419).

Comment: Hello  Shengbao Shui, I don't understand why it is the Azure Rest API instead of the API Management one.
You can see that in the doc, it's supposed to be the API Manager endpoint :

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/apimanagement/logger/createorupdate

Comment: The ·API is to control resource in Azure. API like `/subscriptions/3f0a0802-0a42-4a73-82b2-094d41acd70a/resourceGroups/*` are all Azure Rest API.

Comment: API in this [link](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/apimanagement/apimanagementrest/api-management-rest) is Azure Management API. https://imgur.com/a/z54LM

Comment: https://imgur.com/a/wKg22  This is Azure rest API. You could use the difference with them.

Comment: Sorry, I mean. You could see the difference between them. Hi, does it work now?

Comment: Thanks for your help Shenbao. Anyway it's still not working.

Comment: According to your error log, the root reason is your token is not right. The header is like `Authorization: Bearer $SAS`

Comment: Do you use this API `https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/apimanagement/logger/createorupdate`? why you use `https://waterbalance.management.azure-api.net/loggers/end-user-logger?api-version=2018-01-01`. The API should like `https://management.azure.com/subscriptions/{subscriptionId}/resourceGroups/shuiapi/providers/Microsoft.ApiManagement/service/shuiapi/loggers/{loggerid}?api-version=2017-03-01`

Comment: I am using the API Management rest api like written in this doc :
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/api-management/api-management-howto-log-event-hubs

Comment: Sorry, I am not very good at management API, I suggest you could ask a new question about this.

Answer (score 2):

When the Host is `management.azure.com`, you need to use **Bearer** token authentication

```
PUT /subscriptions/3f0a0802-0a42-4a73-82b2-094d41acd70a/..?api-version=2017-03-01 HTTP/1.1
Authorization: Bearer <bearer-token>
Host: management.azure.com
```

When the host is `<apimservice>.azure-api.net`, then the **SharedAccessSignature** authentication will work.

```
PUT /loggers/mylogger?api-version=2017-03-01 HTTP/1.1
Authorization: SharedAccessSignature <token>
Host: apimService.azure-api.net
```

To generate a Bearer Token you need to refer to [Azure Rest Api](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/#register-your-client-application-with-azure-ad)

Comment: Any idea what is the difference between both endpoints? I need to create a wrapper for reports, wondering which way is better to start with..