# Which is the best way to copy all dashboards from one workspace to another in Azure?

Tags: azure, dashboard, workspace, azure-log-analytics, oms

I have one workspace in Azure Cloud and in which I have lot's of Dashboard, savedSearches and Alerts in `Log-Analytics`(`OMS`). Now I want to copy everything into another workspace how can I do that?

One way that I know is I can export every dashboard from one workspace and import that into other workspace. But I have many dashboards and I  want to copy that into multiple workspace. And also I want to copy all the alerts.

There is a **REST API** available I tried but failed to execute successfully. I've tried following two ways:

1. [Using Postman](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/softwaresimian/2017/10/05/using-postman-to-call-the-graph-api-using-azure-active-directory-aad/)
   **Problem : Authentication Failed with Azure service**
2. [Using Python Script](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/log-analytics/log-analytics-log-search-api-python)
   **Problem : This python Script failed to access URL(403)**

Please suggest me the best way.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: You give your sp `Owner` role? https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-resource-manager/resource-group-create-service-principal-portal#assign-application-to-role

Comment: Thanks @ShengbaoShui-MSFT,  https://management.azure.com/subscriptions/<subscription-id>/resourcegroups/<resource-group-name>/providers/Microsoft.OperationalInsights/workspaces/<work-space-name>/savedSearches?api-version=2015-11-01-preview      I'm using this link to get all savedSearches, Am I wrong here? Because I'm still getting 401 error.

Comment: This is a Azure Rest API,  do you get token firstly?

Comment: Yes, I got token and put in header with Authorization key.   Now I'm getting following ERROR: HTTPError: 400 Client Error: Bad Request for url.

Comment: How do you call your API, you could check my answer about this. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48506272/authenticationfailedinvalidheader-when-using-the-azure-api-management-rest-api/48512595#48512595

Comment: I check the link you provided, the example does not provided `resource`, you could get token like this.  https://imgur.com/a/SuYSn

Comment: I've tried the by postman the way you provided but still getting 400 Bad Request for URL, check if anything wrong with my URL. I want to just export all the alerts and saved seaches, and if possible all the dashboards at once.

Comment: Could you share some screenshot?

Comment: Check this link https://blog.jongallant.com/2017/11/azure-rest-apis-postman/

Comment: May be my setup is wrong somewhere, but forget that and if you can suggest : How can I copy all the dashboards(if possible then with saved seaches and alerts) from one workspace to another.

Comment: The api you used does not work? Honestly speaking I am not good at this.

Comment: Thanks, Actially I'm not good at Azure Cloud itself. But If you know any other way for this : How can I copy all the dashboards(if possible then with saved seaches and alerts) from one workspace to another.

Comment: You check this [blog](https://blogs.technet.microsoft.com/manuelpuron/2017/07/14/export-all-alerts-created-in-a-oms-workspace-to-csv/)?